# Publication list without index in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the [`phys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-phys) `biblatex` style of @Joseph Wright for the bibliography of my PhD thesis. At our institute it is common to also include a separated list of the own publications. So I thought I can also use `biblatex` to generate this list, but I do not want the leading index here. How can I omit the index only in the publication list.

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[natbib=true, backend=biber, %
            style=phys, articletitle=false,biblabel=brackets,%
            chaptertitle=false,pageranges=false, doi=false%
            ]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{lit.bib}
@ARTICLE{Deal1980,
    author = {Deal, B.E.},
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on Electron Devices},
    year = {1980},
    volume = {27},
    pages = {606-608},
    number = {3},
    month = {Mar}
}
@BOOK{Sze1981,
    title = {Physics of Semiconductor Devices},
    publisher = {John Wiley and Sons (WIE)},
    year = {1981},
    author = {S.M. Sze}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mypubs.bib}
@ARTICLE{Me2012,
    author = {Me, I and One, Some and Boss, My},
    journal = {Journal of Nice Physics},
    year = {2012},
    volume = {5},
    pages = {7-8},
    number = {5},
    month = {Jun}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{lit.bib}
\addbibresource{mypubs.bib}

\begin{document}
    \textcite{Deal1980} \textcite{Sze1981}
    \printbibliography
    \begin{refsection}[mypubs.bib]
        \nocite{*}  
        \printbibliography[title=Publications]
    \end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's two ways to do this: on the one hand, you can use the `omitnumbers` option in  `\printbibliography` (the `biblatex` way, which Guido mentioned in the comments); on the other hand, you can define your own `bibenvironment`.

## The `biblatex` way

<sup>Thanks to Guido for pointing this out in the comments</sup>

`biblatex` provides an `omitnumbers` optional argument for `\printbibliography`, which omits the number labels in a bibliography. It requires the package option `defernumbers` to be `true` (which assigns the numeric labels

> This option applies to numerical citation/bibliography styles only and requires that
>   the `defernumbers` option from § 3.1.2.1 be enabled globally. If enabled, biblatex will
>   not assign a numerical label to the entries in the respective bibliography. *This is
>   useful when mixing a numerical subbibliography with one or more subbibliographies
>   using a different scheme* (e. g., author-title or author-year). (§3.6.2 of the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex), my emphasis)

The `phys` style provides two options to format the `labelnumber`: `superscript` and `brackets`, defined in:

```
\DeclareBibliographyOption{biblabel}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{brackets}
    {%
      \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{##1}}%
      \setlength{\biblabelsep}{10 pt}%
    }
    {%
      \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibsuperscript{##1}}%
      \setlength{\biblabelsep}{0 pt}%
    }%
}
```

This checks the value assigned to the `biblabel` option, and changes the `labelnumberwidth` field format accordingly. This format will be already set when the bibliography is printed, and *will be printed in the bibliography, regardless of the `omitnumbers` optional argument* (see the definition of the default `bibliography` bib-environment in `numeric.bbx`). It won't be noted when the `biblabel` option is set to `superscript` (or almost not, since it adds a small horizontal skip), but otherwise what we get is an empty pair of brackets.

So, we must redefine the `labelnumberwidth` field format to do nothing *within our refsection*:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1}
```

<sup>(Don't mind the argument: we're omitting it with `omitnumbers=true` anyway)</sup>

So, the whole `refsection` would be printed with:

```
\begin{refsection}[mypubs.bib]
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[omitnumbers=true,title={My Publications}]
\end{refsection}
```

## The `bibenvironment` way

You can also define your own bibliographic environment with `\defbibenvironment`. I tend to consider this a more semantically adequate way. As an example, I copied the definition from the `authoryear` style, which doesn't place the `labelnumber` (so we don't need to bother with it):

```
\defbibenvironment{mypubs}
 {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

We call it with:

```
\printbibliography[env=mypubs]
```

This MWE shows both approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=phys,biblabel=brackets,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{lit.bib}
@ARTICLE{Deal1980,
    author = {Deal, B.E.},
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on Electron Devices},
    year = {1980},
    volume = {27},
    pages = {606-608},
    number = {3},
    month = {Mar}
}
@BOOK{Sze1981,
    title = {Physics of Semiconductor Devices},
    publisher = {John Wiley and Sons (WIE)},
    year = {1981},
    author = {S.M. Sze}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mypubs.bib}
@ARTICLE{Me2012,
    author = {Me, I and One, Some and Boss, My},
    journal = {Journal of Nice Physics},
    year = {2012},
    volume = {5},
    pages = {7-8},
    number = {5},
    month = {Jun}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}
\addbibresource{mypubs.bib}
\defbibenvironment{mypubs}
 {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\begin{document}
\textcites{Deal1980,Sze1981,Me2012}
\printbibliography[title={Default Bibliography}]
\begin{refsection}[mypubs.bib]
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[omitnumbers=true,title={My Publications, the \texttt{biblatex} way}]
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}[mypubs.bib]
\nocite{*}  
\printbibliography[env=mypubs,title={My Publications, the \texttt{bibenvironment} way}]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: There is no need to define a new `bibenvironment`. Just use the `defernumbers` option of `biblatex` and the `omitnumbers=true` option of `\printbibliography`.

Comment: @Guido I tried that before. It omits the numbers, but the brackets are still there.

Comment: @henrique What if I did not want the [1], [2], [3],... to disappear but rather be changed to [A],[B],[C]? I created a question for this here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319084/defbibenvironment-letters-instead-of-numbers

Comment: @quinmars Apologies for bringing this back from the dead, but I also had the issue with `omitnumbers` leaving behind brackets. It's easy to grab the def for that line and modify with the following: `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\textbullet}` (replace `\textbullet` with whatever you want to be the marker, including nothing). I found this discussion to be immensely helpful in putting together a "Further Reading" section in some lab manuals.