# defbibenvironment letters instead of numbers

Tags: biblatex

I want to print a list of publications at the end of my thesis. I found the following solution [on stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138867/publication-list-without-index-in-biblatex?answertab=votes#tab-top): After the "real" bibliography, I put

```
\defbibenvironment{mypubs}
 {\list
 {}
 {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
  \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
  \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endlist}
{\item}

\begin{refsection}[mypubs.bib]
        \nocite{keyA,keyB,keyC}  
        \printbibliography[env=mypubs,title=List of Publications]
\end{refsection}
```

This creates a separate bibliography and gets rid of [1],[2],[3],... in front of the publications. That is close to, but not exactly what I want. How would I need to change the bibenvironment to get [A],[B],[C]... in front of the publications, instead of [1],[2],[3]...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't plan on citing your own publications (which seems to be the case since you have them confined to a `refsection` anyway), you can just use an `enumerate` modified with the `enumitem` package

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\defbibenvironment{mypubs}
  {\enumerate[label={[\Alph*]}]
     {}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endenumerate}
  {\item}
```

In total

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibenvironment{mypubs}
  {\enumerate[label={[\Alph*]}]
     {}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endenumerate}
  {\item}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography

\begin{refsection}[biblatex-examples.bib]
  \nocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}  
  \printbibliography[env=mypubs,title=List of Publications]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, you can mark your entries with a keyword. Then you can change the format of citations on the fly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{bronto,
  author   = {Anne Elk},
  title    = {Towards a Unified Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date     = {1972-11-16},
  url      = {http://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  urldate  = {2015-09-07},
  keywords = {mine},
}
@online{tric,
  title    = {A Theory on Triceratops},
  author   = {Anne Elk},
  date     = {1972-11-16},
  url      = {https://example.edu/~elk/tric.html#page11},
  urldate  = {2015-09-07},
  keywords = {mine},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\mknumAlph}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@tempcnta=#1\relax
  \ifnum\blx@tempcnta>702 %
  \else
    \ifnum\blx@tempcnta>26 %
      \advance\blx@tempcnta\m@ne
      \divide\blx@tempcnta26\relax
      \blx@numalph\blx@tempcnta
      \multiply\blx@tempcnta26\relax
      \blx@tempcnta=\numexpr#1-\blx@tempcnta\relax
    \fi
  \fi
  \blx@numAlph\blx@tempcnta
  \endgroup}
\def\blx@numAlph#1{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\blx@warning@entry{Value out of range}\number#1\or
  A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\or G\or H\or I\or J\or K\or L\or M\or
  N\or O\or P\or Q\or R\or S\or T\or U\or V\or W\or X\or Y\or Z\else
  \blx@warning@entry{Value out of range}\number#1\fi}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifkeyword{mine}{\mknumAlph{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography

\begin{refsection}[\jobname.bib]
  \nocite{*}  
  \printbibliography[title=List of Publications]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I do want to cite them, but I planned on doing that manually by writing "see publication [A]" into the text. This will not have the hyperref link, but apart from that it is fine.